# Design decision : Adding new arguments to a method V/S creating an instance variable

Tags: java, oop

Lets suppose we have a class **Shape** which has a method **rotate(int velocity)**. This method makes a shape rotate with a speed of velocity(the parameter passed to rotate). This method has been called in a project, say at 100 places.

But now a new requirement comes, that the rotate functionality will also depend on the **color** of the shape, i.e. if the color is blue then the velocity should be decreased by 1, else no change should be made.

- One solution to this problem would be to change the **rotate(int velocity)** method to **rotate(int velocity, Color color)**, then add an if statement inside rotate method to check for the color, and **make a change in 100 calls** of rotate.
  E.g.

  `shape.rotate(50, blue) ;`

Inside the rotate method,

```
void rotate(int velocity, Color color) {
  if(color == blue)
      --velocity ;
}
```

- Another solution would be to make color as an instance variable of the shape object, and then without adding a new argument to the rotate method, simply set the color before calling it, and squeeze the if check inside the rotate method. 
  E.g.

  ```
   shape.setColor(blue) ;
   shape.rotate(50) ;
  ```

  Inside the rotate method,

  ```
  void rotate(int velocity) {
    if(this.color == blue)
      --velocity ;
  }
  ```
- Yet another solution would be to **overload the rotate method** and create a new method named **rotate(int velocity, Color color)** and use it in the new calls. This would leave the existing code which uses **rotate(int velocity)** unchanged.

Which of these would be the best possible solution? **Or, does there exist a better solution?** If yes, then what could it be?

Regards

Comment: If your new property is truly a property of the object (as color IMHO is for shape), then it shouldn't be a parameter for `rotate()` but a property of the object with its own getter and setter.

Comment: Fine, but if color is made an instance variable, what if someone does not call setColor(blue) before the call to rotate(50) ?

Comment: That depends on the domain semantics: is it ok to have a colourless object? Maybe there is a default colour? etc. If it is NOT ok to have a colourless object, then an InvalidStateException should be thrown at the earliest occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good principle of OO is to co-locate related behavior and state. In this case the rotate behavior of shape depends on the colour state of shape, so it makes sense to co-locate both in the Shape class, c.q. create a field 'colour' and use it within the rotate method to customize the rotation behavior.

Apart from this design decision, you are really also asking about a refactoring decision: how do I handle the application code that depends on shape? My approach in cases like this is to think ahead: how many changes like these to the Shape class can we expect? If this is a rare change then you could just go ahead and change all the code locations that initialize the shape class so a colour is set. If shape changes more often, then you should be more rigorous and make your code less tightly coupled. A way to do that in this case is to create an abstract factory (or use the factory offered by a D.I. framework like Spring) so that the application code does not need to know the creation details of shape.

BTW your third option seems sub-optimal to me: part of the code is not made aware of the addition of the colour state to shape, and keeps calling the old 'deprecated' rotate method. This means that setting a shape's colour to blue will not universally affect the rotation behavior, but only in 'special cases'. This weakens the design and makes it harder for the developers after you to understand it.

Comment: As for the third option: you can implement the 'old' method as follows: `void rotate(int velocity) {
rotate(velocity, getColor())
}` to handle that problem. No code has to be changed, and the 'new' logic is used everywhere. AND if you then use the invalidStateException when no color is set, you are on the safe side.

Comment: If color is unset your solution could result in an error.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there are a couple of questions you need to ask yourself.

1. Do you care about the color outside of the `rotate` method? If yes, make it an instance variable; if no, pass it to the rotate method.
2. Are you likely to care about the color outside of the `rotate` method further down the line? If yes, make it an instance variable; if no, pass it to the rotate method.
3. Are you always going to care about the color when calling the rotate method? If yes, make it an argument (to force them to set the color when rotating the shape).

Comment: I think you are right, but this brings to my mind new questions: 

Referring to point 3. of your answer, wouldn't it be better to create a new overloaded method `rotate(int velocity, Color color)` so that the code which uses the existing `rotate(int velocity)` method does not have to be changed.

Moreover, in this case, there might be transparent objects (say, in the existing code) that do not have any color and have been using the `rotate(int velocity)` method till now. If we add another argument to `rotate`, these calls would have to pass in `null` as the argument for the color parameter.

Comment: @vaibhav That would be the 'no' answer to question 3, surely? If you're not always going to care about the color then you don't want to force them to specify one, and having two rotate methods would be the way to go.

Comment: colour is a property of shape. Once you decide to add it, silently ignoring it in the old rotate method is a bit misleading. What you could do is specify in the JavaDoc that a certain default colour will be used if none is set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the first option is is tedious to implement. What if you miss at one place, what if later u realize that you need rotate(single parameter) again.
2. The second option is irrelevant as many have already pointed out.
3. 3rd I think is the best solution, as it will not break your code. You can have both the overloaded method, can use any of them as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I see classic example of inheritance usage here.

```
class Shape {
  public void rotate(int v) {}
}

class GreenShape extends Shape {
  public void rotate(int v){
    super.rotate(v + 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a poor design choice, both from an OO-perspective (avoid straight subclassing if possible because it creates tight coupling) as from a domain modelling perspective (colour is a property of shape with potentially a lot of different values, so should be modelled as property, not a subclass)